# which marathi(india) font maps exactly with the qwerty keyboard

Tags: c#, fonts

I want a marathi (local language in india) font having its virtual keyboard layout such that whenever I type a word in English it will convert to marathi, exactly similar to what is used in orkut. I want to use it with c#.

Comment: i have downloaded kf-kiran.ttf font and installed it. but when i set it to the textbox(c# .net) it shows me that cant set the font bcoz only ttf fonts are supported. can anybody tell me about this

Comment: make use of richtextbox control and then try

Answer (score 0):

try : [Google Language API Family](http://code.google.com/apis/language/)

Also check this : http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/reference.html

Comment: i downloded a font kf-kiran.ttf. I have installed the font. but when i set this font to a text box it shows me unable to set bcoz it is not ttf font...y so?